# Where can I find the Orthodox response to the Augsburg Confession?

Tags: church-history, eastern-orthodox, lutheranism, creeds-and-confessions, resource-request

According to [Steven Runciman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steven_Runciman)'s *[The Great Church in Captivity](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521313104)* ([excerpt](http://orthodoxinfo.com/inquirers/tca_luther.aspx)), the Orthodox Patriarch [Jeremias II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeremias_II_of_Constantinople) wrote a letter detailing the differences between the Orthodox doctrines and Lutheran teachings.

Is an English translation of the letter publicly available, and where can I find it? My searches keep taking me back to the linked book excerpt above.

Comment: I don't think that there was one letter. It was a correspondence... From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patriarch_Jeremias_II_of_Constantinople) `"On 24 May 1575, Lutherans Jakob Andreae and Martin Crusius from Tübingen presented the Patriarch with a translated copy of the Augsburg Confession. Jeremias II wrote three rebuttals known as 'Answers,' which established that the Orthodox Church had no desire for reformation.[7]"`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> ## Is an English translation of the letter publicly available, and where can I find it?

If you are talking about finding it online, you aren't going to have any luck. These letters, as far as I know, are not available to read online.

However, if you are willing to spend some money, an English book compilation of the letters by George Mastrantonis can be [bought from Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0916586820) (published by [Holy Cross Orthodox Press](http://store.holycrossbookstore.com/), however it seems to be [more expensive](http://store.holycrossbookstore.com/916586820.html) on their website).

Quoting a review on Amazon by [Dusk](http://www.amazon.com/gp/pdp/profile/A30B4ZKMKLQLPA/ref=cm_cr_pr_pdp):

> This book is very meaty, but I recommend it strongly to those interested. The letters provide a deeper understanding of both Lutheran and Orthodox beliefs. They provide a window into the age they were written in: the manners used in disagreement are delightful. They also provide a look into human nature itself. Read carefully or you may injure yourself.

I hope this helps! Have fun...

Comment: Excerpts from the Mastrantonis translation can currently be read here: http://orthodoxinfo.com/ecumenism/jeremiah.aspx

Comment: Oh, yes @MετάEd, thank you for that link. I saw it but didn't think of adding it.